# Solve transfer function with non-zero initial conditions

Tags: control-systems

### Hand computation

I have a transfer function defined as $\frac{0.6p+1}{0.6p^2+2.2p+8}$ which was derived from a circuit. Solving this by hand gives the equation, $$i(t)=Ce^{-1.83t}\cos(3.16t + \phi)$$

We can find $C$ and $\phi$ by using the initial conditions of $i(0)=1$ and $\frac{di}{dt}(0)=-8$. This gives us the equation, $$i(t)=2.194e^{-1.83t}\cos(3.16t + 63^{\circ})$$

### Mathematica

To solve this transfer function I do,

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[(0.6 p + 1)/(0.6 p^2 + 2.2 p + 8), p];
out = OutputResponse[tf, UnitStep[t], t]

Plot[{out, 2.194 Exp[-1.83 t] Cos[3.16 t + 63 \[Degree]]}, {t, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

I know I need to input the aforementioned initial conditions but where in the code does this go? I'm assuming the `UnitStep` is where I'm going wrong.

[image: output of plot function]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the output response with litteral initial states `c1` and `c2` and then resolve `c1` and `c2` only at end :

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[(0.6 p + 1)/(0.6 p^2 + 2.2 p + 8), p]
ss = StateSpaceModel[tf]
y[t_] = OutputResponse[{ss, {c1, c2}}, 0, t][[1]] // Chop
```

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> 1. E^(-1.83333 t) (1. c2 Cos[3.15788 t] - 4.22224 c1 Sin[3.15788 t] - 
>      0.580558 c2 Sin[3.15788 t]) + 
>      1.66667 E^(-1.83333 t) (1. c1 Cos[3.15788 t] + 
>      0.580558 c1 Sin[3.15788 t] + 0.316668 c2 Sin[3.15788 t])

```
constantsListRule = Solve[{y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 8}, {c1, c2}][[1]]
yy[t_] = y[t] /. constantsListRule
Plot[yy[t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> {c1 -> -1., c2 -> 2.66667}
>
> 1.66667 E^(-1.83333 t) (-1. Cos[3.15788 t] + 
>       0.26389 Sin[3.15788 t]) + 
>    1. E^(-1.83333 t) (2.66667 Cos[3.15788 t] + 2.67408 Sin[3.15788 t])
>
> [image]

Answer (score 3):

There are no states $i(t)$ and $i'(t)$ in the transfer function. Moreover, the usual assumption in transfer functions is zero initial conditions. So first, the problem has to be translated to a state-space representation with the desired states.

```
ioEq = Control`DEqns`ioEqnsForm[
       TransferFunctionModel[(0.6 p + 1)/(0.6 p^2 + 2.2 p + 8), p]]; 
states = Flatten@{ioEq[[1, 2]], D[ioEq[[1, 2]], ioEq[[-1]]]};
ssm = StateSpaceModel[ioEq[[1, 1]], states, ioEq[[-3]], ioEq[[1, 2]], ioEq[[-1]]];
```

> [image]

Then set the desired initial conditions and simulate.

```
ssm = StateSpaceModel[ssm, Thread[states -> {1, 8}]];
or = OutputResponse[ssm, 0, {t, 0, 5}];
Plot[or, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

(The result here is what is expected when $i'(0)==8$. The result you have with the hand calculation is with $i'(0)==-8$.)

Comment: are you able to explain this code? I understand the second block you submitted, but the first I have very little idea what it means. What would I change in order to have i'(0)=-8?

Comment: For $i'(0)==-8$, do ssm = StateSpaceModel[ssm, Thread[states -> {1, -8}]]. The first part is converting the transfer function to ODEs and assembling them as a state space model with states $i(t)$ and $i'(t)$.